# Powershell select class window active/visible

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with my Powershell ISE automation when I hit office documents that have password protection. There is apparently no parameter for passing password in powerpoint for example unlike excel.

When the windows dialog box pops up, that is where my script breaks down.

I need to able to pass a variable or SEND KEYS to that active window.

The window class is #32770.

How can I set a windows class of #32770 in powershell so I can incorporate SENDKEYS to that window in a loop as I open and close docs with passwords?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [AutoIt cmdlets for Powershell](https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/).

Script will be like this:

```
Wait-AU3WinActive -Title "Input password"
Send-AU3Key -Key "p@$$w0rd"
```